# Alert TableData

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to alert the TableData is `onclick id: key`?

```
$('#sampleTbl tr').each(function(row, tr){
        TableData = TableData 
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text() + ' '  // Task No.
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text() + ' '  // Date
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text() + ' '  // Description
            + $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text() + ' '  // Task
            + '\n';
    });
```

I just want to know if it get the text in those tr.

Comment: can you provide fiddle????

Comment: Also, you should return the TableData.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
//insert this code within each function:
if (!$(this).text().trim().length) {
        //do the stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sampleTbl tr').each(function(row, tr){
        TableData = TableData 
            + $( this ).find('td:eq(0)').text() + ' '  // Task No.
            + $( this ).find('td:eq(1)').text() + ' '  // Date
            + $( this ).find('td:eq(2)').text() + ' '  // Description
            + $( this ).find('td:eq(3)').text() + ' '  // Task
            + '\n';
    });
```